# When $PGL(n,q)$ is simple

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

I need to find all pairs $(n,q)$ with $n \geq 2$ for which $PGL(n,q)$ is simple.

We proved in the course that $PSL(n,q)$ is simple provided that  $n \geq 2$ and $(n,q) \ne (2,2)$ or $(2,3)$. I also have read in one of the posts that $PGL(n,\mathbb{F})=PSL(n,\mathbb{F})$ if and only if every element of $\mathbb{F}$ has an nth root in $\mathbb{F}$.($\mathbb{F}$ is finite field)

So, can we say these are all the cases when $PGL(n,q)$ is simple? I feel this is not complete argument!

Comment: Note $PSL(n,q)$ is a normal subgroup of $PGL(n,q)$, so if they are not equal that automatically means $PGL(n,q)$ is not simple. Thus, $PGL(n,q)$ is simple precisely when it equals $PSL(n,q)$ and $PSL(n,q)$ is simple. So what is incomplete about this argument?

Comment: @runway44, I am just wondering if there is a case I missed.

Comment: Well you need to point out that ${\rm PSL}(n,q)$ is nontrivial when $(n,q) \ne (2,2)$ or $(2,3)$.

Comment: you also have to determine explicitely for which $(n,q)$ every element of $\mathbb{F}_q$ has a $n$th-root if you want a complete answer.

Comment: @GreginGre, you are right, I think every element of $\mathbb{F}_q$ has an $n$th-root if and only if $n$ divides $q-1$, right?

Comment: no. To the contrary, $n$ needs to be coprime to $q-1$